# „Sich bewusst machen, dass" oder „Sich dessen bewusst machen, dass"?

Tags: grammar-identification, genitive

Bei einer Aufgabe habe ich geschrieben

> Da macht Werther sich dessen bewusst, dass seine Lage ausweglos ist

während die Antwort heißt

> Da macht Werther sich bewusst, dass....

Könnte man trotzdem "dessen" verwenden, oder überhaupt nicht? Wäre

> Da macht es sich Werter bewusst, dass...

auch eine Möglichkeit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es heißt *sich einer Sache bewusst sein* mit Genitivobjekt, aber *sich eine Sache bewusst machen* mit Akkusativobjekt. Das ist der Grund, warum das *dessen* in deinem ersten Beispiel falsch ist.

In allen Beispielen kann der Objektsatz das Objekt ersetzen. Ob du da noch ein zusätzliches *es* einschiebst oder es weglässt, ist Geschmackssache. Es wird manchmal verwendet, um den Rhythmus des Satzes zu verbessern.

Answer (score -1):

Es gibt zwei Wendungen, die das Adverb (/Adjektiv) "bewußt" verwenden:

> sich *Akkusativobjekt* bewußt **machen**
> sich *Genitivobjekt* bewußt **sein**

Die erste Wendung bezeichnet den *Akt*. Mögliche Synonyme wären "erkennen" oder "sich *Akkusativobjekt* ins Gedächtnis rufen".

Die zweite Wendung bezeichnet den *Zustand*, der die Folge dieses Akts ist: nachdem man sich etwas *bewußt gemacht* hat, ist man *sich dessen bewußt*. Ein mögliches Synonym dafür wäre "wissen".

Comment: Die derzeit orthografisch korrekte Schreibung ist [bewusst](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bewusst).

Comment: @guidot: die orthographisch korrekte Schreibung von "orthographisch" ist "orthographisch", wenn man auch nur irgendeinen Unterschied zwischen einem Graphen und einem Grafen sieht. In Sachen "scharfes s" würde dir jedenfalls Adelung widersprechen,